# Progressive or Interlace detection in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to write a decoder using ffmpeg and I want to display some information about the video stream. I can detect if a frame is progressive or interlaced (tff, bff) only after decoding the frame. i.e,

```
avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &gotFrame, &packet);
.....(assume we have a frame) 
.....
// print information
printf("prog=%d inter=%d", !pFrame->interlaced_frame, pFrame->interlaced_frame);
```

This works well.

But I want to know if there is a way of detecting this from the AVFormatContext, AVCodecCtx or AVCodec structs or some other functions. This would be very useful, if for example I want to abort decoding if the file is interlaced. I don't want to decode a frame to get this piece of information.

I am trying to support MPEG2, H.264/AVC and HEVC codecs (either elementary streams or in MP4 container).

Sorry if this is a trivial question! Thank you very much!

Comment: In my decoder I decode the first several frames to get some information about the video stream, including whether it is interlaced in exactly the same way you do here. So there may be some other way, but if there is, I could never figure it out. And I would wonder about the reliability even if a way were found. I would want to test it thoroughly before switching over to using it.

Comment: Thanks @njahnke .. I hope someone else takes a stab at this. I'll keep looking in the meantime!

Comment: `AVStream->parser->field_order`, `AVStream.codecpar.field_order` and `AVCodecContext.field_order`, which are all of type `AVFieldOrder`, seem to be all promising but must be tested. In particular the last two may be unset on decoding, so not useful. I will test them in the following days and let you know.

Answer (score 8):

ffmpeg can run in "idet" (interlace detection) mode and gives a summary of frame types it finds in the file. I use:

```
$ ffmpeg -filter:v idet -frames:v 360 -an -f rawvideo -y /dev/null -i HitchhikersGuide.mp4
```

(ffmpeg with the idet filter, sample 360 frames, blocking audio, using rawvideo format, send output to /dev/null, with input file HitchhikersGuide.mp4)

which produces a report that contains (in part):

```
[Parsed_idet_0 @ 0x7fd5f3c121c0] Repeated Fields: Neither:   360 Top:     0 Bottom:     0
[Parsed_idet_0 @ 0x7fd5f3c121c0] Single frame detection: TFF:    30 BFF:     0 Progressive:   330 Undetermined:     0
[Parsed_idet_0 @ 0x7fd5f3c121c0] Multi frame detection: TFF:    22 BFF:     0 Progressive:   338 Undetermined:     0
```

In this case, 92% of the sampled frames are progressive, and 8% are interlaced, so most services would call this an interlaced video. TFF and BFF are Top-Field-First and Bottom-Field-First, respectively, and both indicate an interlaced frame.

Note that it is possible to encode interlaced video as progressive and progressive video as interlaced, and this method will report on the encoding only. If you want to know if the video was originally interlaced or progressive, then you will need to visually inspect it and look for a "combing" effect where alternate lines don't quite line up with each other (especially when the camera is moving fast), and if you see combing, then the original video is interlaced.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [ffprobe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips), which comes with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#get-packages). I don't know how you would use that from a library, but the command-line version can show the `field_order`.
Example command, with a few additional fields:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v stream=codec_name,height,width,pix_fmt,field_order -of csv=p=0 "$Your_File"
```

Example output with different files:

```
prores,1920,1080,yuva444p12le,progressive
h264,1920,1080,yuv420p,unknown              # some progressive files show unknown
prores,720,576,yuv422p10le,tb               # tb = interlaced TFF interleaved
mpeg2video,1920,1080,yuv422p,tt             # tt = interlaced TFF
dvvideo,720,576,yuv420p,bt                  # bt = interlaced BFF interleaved
```

An alternative would be [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) :

```
mediainfo --Inform='Video;%ScanType%,%ScanOrder%,%ScanType_StoreMethod%' "$Your_File"
```

Example output with different files:

```
Progressive,,
Interlaced,TFF,
Interlaced,TFF,InterleavedFields
Interlaced,BFF,InterleavedFields
```

Mediainfo's source is available [here](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Source), and [on Github](https://github.com/JeromeMartinez).

Comment: After a lot of testing, I've found that `ffprobe` cannot reliably identify interlace. Polling every 1sec on a known interlaced RTP stream, it correctly detected interlace only 30% of the time.  Changing `analyzeduration` to as long as 120 sec had no effect.